# Cant store api data called by axios in array through mounted, unless clicking on <Root> element from vue devtools (in browser)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

i'm  using axios to get data from api and store in an array after mounting then run a search query in the array later on, but it's not working unless i click on Root element in browsers Vue developer tools, after i click on vue Root element from vue dev tool everything works fine.Here is my code..

```
    <script type="module">
          const vueApp = new Vue({
             el: "#pos",
             data: {
                searchTerm: "",
                allProducts: [],
                selectedProducts: [],
                suggestions: []
             },
             mounted: function (){
               axios.get("api/products").then( res => this.allProducts = res.data );
             },
             methods: {
                select(item){
                   this.selectedProducts.push(item);
                   this.suggestions = [];
                }
             },
             computed:{
                matches(){
                   if(!this.searchTerm) return;
                   this.suggestions = this.allProducts.filter(sP=>(sP.prod_name).includes(this.searchTerm));
                }
             }
    });
    </script>

    //HTML below------------------
<div id="pos">
    <input type="text" v-model="searchTerm">
         <ul v-for="match in suggestions">
             <li @click="select(match)">
                  {{match.prod_name}}
             </li>
         </ul>

    <table>
    <tr v-for="(product,i) in selectedProducts">
      <td>@{{product.prod_name}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

```js
const vueApp = new Vue({
  el: "#pos",
  data: {
    searchTerm: "",
    allProducts: [],
    selectedProducts: [],
    suggestions: []
  },
  mounted: function() {
    axios.get("api/products").then(res => this.allProducts = res.data);
  },
  methods: {
    select(item) {
      this.selectedProducts.push(item);
      this.suggestions = [];
    }
  },
  computed: {
    matches() {
      if (!this.searchTerm) return;
      this.suggestions = this.allProducts.filter(sP => (sP.prod_name).includes(this.searchTerm));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="pos">
  <input type="text" v-model="searchTerm">
  <ul v-for="match in suggestions">
    <li @click="select(match)">
      {{match.prod_name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried just using `mounted() { ...}` instead? I've never run across this issue

Comment: Not working with mounted( ){...} either,
still i need to click on <Root> from vue dev tools .

Comment: is this the root element that is calling this code? because if so that would make sense.

Comment: Yes i have only one instance as well as one root element in this case, could you please explain why this is happening and how to solve it? 
my humble thanks :)

Comment: Without any extra information it seems as though your app is behaving as expected. What are you expecting to behave differently?

Comment: i'm trying to do something like load all the produtcs from database with axios.get into allProducts array right after the document is loaded.

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: I'm running a search query in the allProducts array, unless i click on the <Root> from vue dev tools nothing can be found , but after clicking i can search and find the products by my searchTerm string.

Comment: I don't see your `searchTerm` declared in your data? I also don't see how that would have anything to do with the `mounted` lifecycle hook?

Comment: Sidenote, if this is in a component, `data` should be a function that returns an object

Comment: you are using looping through `suggestions` but not `allProducts` -- is there any other code that you are using that would reference allProducts?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments on your question, this is an error I cannot seem to understand how you are getting. I sense there is information that we are not being presented with.

As such, here is a quick "working" example of fetching items from the `mounted` lifecycle hook in a component. Note: If you are creating the component via a Single-File Component (.vue files) then don't worry too much about the declaration, pay attention only to the data and mounted methods.

```js
const App = Vue.component('App', {
  template: `<div>
    <input v-model="searchTerm" type="search">
    {{items.length}} results fetched
  </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      searchTerm: '',
      items: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    //Timeout used to mimic axios query
    setTimeout(()=> this.items= [1,2,3,4], 1000)
  }
});

const app = new App({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">Placeholder</div>
```

### Edit

The code you have given us after your update seems to be working just fine. See the below snippet.

I noticed you are looping over `suggestions` but that value is never updated anywhere in your given code.

```js
const vueApp = new Vue({
  el: "#pos",
  data: {
    searchTerm: "",
    allProducts: [],
    selectedProducts: [],
    suggestions: []
  },
  mounted: function() {
    setTimeout(() => this.allProducts = [1,2,3,4,5], 1000);
  },
  methods: {
    select(item) {
      this.selectedProducts.push(item);
      this.suggestions = [];
    }
  },
  computed: {
    matches() {
      if (!this.searchTerm) return;
      this.suggestions = this.allProducts.filter(sP => (sP.prod_name).includes(this.searchTerm));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="pos">
  <input type="text" v-model="searchTerm">
  <ul v-for="match in suggestions">
    <li @click="select(match)">
      {{match.prod_name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  {{allProducts.length}} results loaded
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated all the codes i'm trying with. i'm not using any components just used CDN and a single vue instance .
thanks again really appreciate your help.

Comment: @MilonHossain I've edited my question with an updated version of your answer -- please take a look and let me know if that might help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
mounted: function(){
      var _self = this;
       axios.get("api/products").then( res => _self.allProducts = res.data );
     }
```